# How to encode OpenCV IplImage with H263 or MPEG-4 codecs?

Tags: opencv, video-encoding

I'm working on a win32 project under Visual Studio 2010, And I need to encode the IplImage to MPEG-4 for example.

Is there any library to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows there are few multimedia APIs: VFW (obsolete), DirectShow, Media Foundation. All three have options for video encoders. Perhaps most of the options are with DirectShow, though Media Foundation offers MPEG-4 Part 10 (H.264) encoder out of the box in Windows 7. There are also additional options which don't involve Windows APIs: ffmpeg, Intel IPP just to name a new. With all of them you will perhaps have to put some effort into integration of your application with these APIs/libraries.